# What conditions are required on the domain of a real function in order to ask about its limits at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

In order for the question whether the function $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has a limit at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ to make sense, one requires $a$ to be a limit point a $X$, that is, that one of the following conditions are satisfied:

$(1)$ for any neighborhood $U$ of $a$ in $X, X$ contains a point of $U$ distinct from $a$;

$(2)$ there is a sequence in $X\setminus\{a\}$ which converges to $a$ in $U$.

What is the appropriate generalization of this condition for limits at $+\infty$ or $-\infty$? One thing that comes to mind is to require $X$ to be unbounded above in the case of $+\infty$ and unbounded below in the case of $-\infty$.

Amann and Escher (the book *Analysis I*) define a neighborhood of an $+\infty$ (resp., $-\infty$) to be a subset $U$ of the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ for which there is $\epsilon > 0$ with the property that $(\epsilon,+\infty) \subseteq U$ (resp., $(-\infty,\epsilon) \subseteq U$). In this language, the condition $(1)$ precisely says that $U$ is unbounded above (resp., below).

Comment: "Unbounded above" and "containing some interval $(\epsilon, \infty)$" are two completely different criteria.

Comment: @Arthur Of course. What did lead you to believe I think otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition for it to be meaningful to ask whether $f$ has a limit at $+\infty$ ($-\infty$, resp.) is precisely that $X$ be unbounded above (below, resp.). The definition of nbhds of $\pm\infty$ given by Amann and Escher is the only reasonable one in this context and makes limits at $\pm\infty$ behave just like limits at any real number. In particular, they make the extended real line $\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ homeomorphic to the closed unit interval $[0,1]$.